# JS progress bar color not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I work with progress bars with using jQuery.

So problem is, I define standard colors, which I want to show at my progress bar depends of value which I received.

My code:

```js
var defaultSegmentColors = ['#FF6363', '#FEF567', '#70FE67'];

function move(value, color, barID) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(barID);
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= value) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
      $('.myBar').css("background-color", color);
    }
  }
}


function refresh(barElem) {
  var color = "";
  var elements = {
    value: parseInt($(barElem).attr('value')),
    idBar: $(barElem).attr('value-field')
  }

  if (elements['value'] <= 50) {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[0];

  } else if (elements['value'] <= 80) {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[1];

  } else if (elements['value'] <= 85) {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[2];

  }



  move(elements['value'], color, elements['idBar']);
}




$('[data-type="sfcs-progres-bar"]').each(function() {
  refresh(this);
});
```

```css
#myProgress {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #535353;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar0" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="43" value-field="myBar0"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar1" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="80" value-field="myBar1"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar2" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="90" value-field="myBar2"></div>
</div>
```

As u can see I have function at which I can check **elements['value']** and in the end I return some color value from array **defaultSegmentColors** at which I have **hex colors**.

But in the end result I recived standart color which I have from CSS file, maybe somebody will see mistake. Because I waste the half day to find it, and yet I still didn't.

Answer (score 2):

This provides what you're looking for. By looping through the `.myBar` class, it is taking the value of the final element and assigning it to all of your bars - changing the class to the `barID` value results in the colours appearing as you want them to appear.

```js
var defaultSegmentColors = ['#FF6363', '#FEF567', '#70FE67'];

function move(value, color, barID) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(barID);
  var width = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= value) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';

      
      $('#' + barID).css("background-color", color);
    }
  }
}


function refresh(barElem) {
  var color = "";
  var elements = {
    value: parseInt($(barElem).attr('value')),
    idBar: $(barElem).attr('value-field')
  }

  if (elements['value'] <= 50) {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[0];

  } else if (elements['value'] <= 80) {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[1];

  } else {
    color = defaultSegmentColors[2];

  }

  move(elements['value'], color, elements['idBar']);
}




$('[data-type="sfcs-progres-bar"]').each(function() {
  refresh(this);
});
```

```css
#myProgress {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.myBar {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #535353;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar0" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="43" value-field="myBar0"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar1" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="80" value-field="myBar1"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar2" class="myBar" data-type="sfcs-progres-bar" value="90" value-field="myBar2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As u can see progress bar #3 is black, but it's must be another color

Comment: The green colour was only available between 81 and 85, because of the following part: `else if (elements['value'] <= 85)`. Turn this in to `else` and it will provide the green colour you need :) I've edited my snippet to match this.